# E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap'

Tags: android, dalvik

When I run my app on emulator, Android Studio shows this error:

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced
>   from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Restarter.getActivities

How can I solve that?

Comment: Unless for some reason you named your app `com.android.tools.fd.runtime` or something like that, you can't, as it is not your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayMap is in the Support Library.  You need to add it to the dependencies in build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0"
}
```

Comment: How can i do that plz?

Comment: @NeamatTabani Using AndroidStudio, open the PROJECT TAB (ribbon on the left), choose option GRADLE SCRIPTS -> build.gradle (Module:app), scroll down to "dependencies".

Comment: you may need to change library version, according to what packages you have installed in your IDE (this is for version `24.2.0`, but you could have `23.3.0` instead and it would work).

Comment: @tonygil you should post this as an answer